# serving MYSQL from local machine to other remote users via heroku

Tags: mysql, node.js, heroku

I have hosted my backend to heroku but as heroku asks for credit card details.
I want  heroku to use my local machines mysql. How can I do this ?
I would need to write my system IP instead of localhost. And where else I need to make changes  ?

Comment: Unless your local machine allows remote connections this is a non-starter. Even if it did you'd have to keep your machine online and running at all times, which is impractical.

Comment: I need to do this for some testing purpose only. 
Is there any way that somehow I can pull it off ? @tadman

Comment: You might want to try a different hosting platform. There's many alternatives to Heroku, and a lot of them offer a free tier of some sort, even Amazon AWS/EC2.

Comment: Normally you'd do this with an SSH tunnel, but not sure you have access on Heroku to pop open a port. You could try something like [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com) for your MySQL service. Honestly, if you're running your database locally, why not run the whole app locally and use something like Ngrok to make it accessible?

Comment: yeaa thr'z always an option . Bt still I wanted to make this thing work for my satisfaction :) .

Comment: It's off-topic on here as it's more server/computer related than programming.

Comment: yeeha. Actually I am working on service workers and to send FCM notifications I will need SSL. That's the reason I deployed temporarily on heroku

Comment: Again: Ngrok or something like it. This supports HTTPS if you need it.

Comment: Ok. I will give it a try :). ty